# Cannot convert value of type "ViewController.Type" to expected argument type "UIViewController"

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make an Alert Controller in which, if the Answer is "Ok", then it will perform a segue to a MapView. Here's the full code:

```
@IBAction func teste(_ sender: Any) {

    // Create the alert controller
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Reservar vaga?", message: "Uma vaga será reservada em Estapar Estacionamento.", preferredStyle: .alert)

    // Create the actions
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(alert:UIAlertAction) -> Void in

        let confirmAction = UIAlertController(title: "Vaga confirmada", message: "Gostaria de ter direções ao local?", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let okConfirmAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Sim", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:{(alert:UIAlertAction) -> Void in

            presentViewController(ViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })

        let noConfirmAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Não", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("Ok Pressed")
        }

        confirmAction.addAction(okConfirmAction)
        confirmAction.addAction(noConfirmAction)
        self.present(confirmAction, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) {
        UIAlertAction in
        NSLog("Cancel Pressed")
    }

    // Add the actions
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    //Append the button to the view
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I'm having trouble in this part:

```
let okConfirmAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Sim", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:{(alert:UIAlertAction) -> Void in

    presentViewController(ViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

When i try to use presentViewController, this error appears: "Cannot convert value of type "ViewController.Type" to expected argument type 'UIViewController'"

And when I try to use performSegue, I use is this way:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "teste", sender: (Any).self)
```

And then the following error appears: "Implitcit use of self in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit"

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I assume that ViewController is class name, not class instance -  hence the problem

Comment: @Miknash can you please explain a little more? I'm new to swift :p

Comment: Do you have class ViewController? or do you have var ViewController: MyViewController?

Comment: I have two viewControllers, the first one named ViewController (linked to the map view I want to show after the segue) and the second one named ViewController2 (linked to the initial view of the app)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So to fix the `presentViewController(ViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` function in the `okConfirmAction` closure, try this:

```
self?.present(ViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And for the `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` function in the `okConfirmAction` closure, try:

```
self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "teste", sender: self)
```

As it is a closure you have to use self before calling the function. This is to make you aware that you may cause a retain cycle.

Write the closure as follows to prevent the retain cycle (using a weak `self` reference means we replace `self` with `self?` as a prefix for `present(_:animated:completion:)` and `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`):

```
let okConfirmAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Sim", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:{ [weak self] (alert:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
//insert code from above
})
```

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot! I used the function you showed me in performSegue and it went alright :)

Comment: @LucasLeal you accepted other answer - if this one is correct please accept this one

Answer (score 0):

Use `performSegue(withIdentifier: "teste", sender: self)`. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the `(Any).` before `self`, since `self` on a class name returns the *type* of the class, not an instance of the class.

Comment: I use     (Any). before     self because the console told me to do this, honestly (kinda new to the language)... when I use     self only, it responds me "Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit".

Comment: Ah. That happens only when you're in a block, and you usually just have to prefix your variables with `self?.`.