# Cannot convert value of type 'ViewController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, types, uicontainerview

I have analyzed **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45331626/cannot-convert-value-of-type-viewcontroller-type-to-expected-argument-type-ui)** question already but it is about `alertController`
What actually I am doing is that, I am working with `ContainerViews` to a `MasterVC`. I am following this **[Tutorial](https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/)**. 
When I am coming to `updateView()` function and adding or removing the controllers on these lines I am facing this error.

> Cannot convert value of type 'ViewController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

[image]

```
import UIKit

class MasterViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func segmentcontrol(_ sender: Any) {
}

@IBOutlet weak var segmentedCont: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var cancelMaster: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func cancelMasterAct(_ sender: Any) {
}

@IBOutlet weak var createMaster: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func createMasterAct(_ sender: Any) {
}


func setupView() {
    setupSegmentedControl()

    updateView()
}
private func setupSegmentedControl() {

   //  Configure Segmented Control

    segmentedCont.removeAllSegments()
    segmentedCont.insertSegment(withTitle: "Instock", at: 0, animated: false)
    segmentedCont.insertSegment(withTitle: "Checkin", at: 1, animated: false)
    segmentedCont.insertSegment(withTitle: "Inspection", at: 2, animated: false)
    segmentedCont.insertSegment(withTitle: "Checkout", at: 3, animated: false)
    segmentedCont.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectionDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    // Select First Segment
    segmentedCont.selectedSegmentIndex = 0


}

@objc func selectionDidChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    updateView()
}

private func updateView() {


    if segmentedCont.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        remove(asChildViewController: CheckinViewController)
        remove(asChildViewController: CheckoutViewController)
        remove(asChildViewController: InspectionViewController)
        add(asChildViewController: InstockViewController)
    }
    if segmentedCont.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        remove(asChildViewController: InstockViewController)
        remove(asChildViewController: CheckinViewController)
        remove(asChildViewController: InspectionViewController)
        add(asChildViewController: CheckinViewController)
    }
    if segmentedCont.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        remove(asChildViewController: InstockViewController)
        remove(asChildViewController: CheckoutViewController)
        remove(asChildViewController: CheckinViewController)
        add(asChildViewController: InspectionViewController)

    }

    else {
            remove(asChildViewController: InstockViewController)
            remove(asChildViewController: CheckinViewController)
            remove(asChildViewController: InspectionViewController)
            add(asChildViewController: CheckoutViewController)
    }

}


private func add(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    // Add Child View Controller
    addChildViewController(viewController)

    // Add Child View as Subview
    view.addSubview(viewController.view)

    // Configure Child View
    viewController.view.frame = view.bounds
    viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    // Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}

private lazy var CheckinViewController : CheckinViewController = {
    // Load Storyboard
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

    // Instantiate View Controller
    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CheckinViewController") as! CheckinViewController

    // Add View Controller as Child View Controller
    self.add(asChildViewController: viewController)

    return viewController
}()

private lazy var  InstcokViewController : InstockViewController = {
    // Load Storyboard
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name : "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

    // Instantiate View Controller
    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InstockViewController") as! InstockViewController

    // Add View Controller as Child View Controller
    self.add(asChildViewController: viewController)

    return viewController
}()



private func remove(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    // Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)

    // Remove Child View From Superview
    viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()

    // Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.removeFromParentViewController()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setupView()
    print("MasterVC Printed")
    self.view.addSubview(segmentedCont)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.52, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white

    segmentedCont.tintColor = UIColor.black

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your functions (e.g. add(asChildViewController:) ) take UIViewController **instances** and you are trying to pass **types** instead.

In other words you are telling "Add CheckoutViewController" not telling specifically which one CheckoutViewController should be added.

You have to create view controller before adding it somewhere. For example, if you use storyboards:

```
if segmentedCont.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
    guard let instockVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Instock") as? InstockViewController else { return }
    add(asChildViewController: instockVC)
}
```

For deletion I suggest to see this answer: [How to remove the ChildViewController from Parent View Controller in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367588/how-to-remove-the-childviewcontroller-from-parent-view-controller-in-swift-3)

Comment: How can I add??

Comment: Please update the answer so error should be resolved> plz

Answer (score 0):

You are attempt to remove a view controller type, instead of an instance of a view controller. Consider this line:

```
remove(asChildViewController: InstockViewController)
```

`InstockViewController` is a *type* of view controller. You need to pass an *instance* of that type.

EDIT: In the tutorial you referenced, he explains this in the section "Adding a Child View Controller". There he shows how the master view controller creates instances of the view controllers to be contained.

Comment: What should I write there

Comment: See my edit. Read the tutorial more carefully, it's explained there.

Comment: If you aren't clear between the difference between an instance and a type, you are going to struggle.